# ASPxTextBox ErrorText Not Updated on Lost Focus

Tags: c#, javascript, devexpress, client-side-validation

I got this `ASPxTextBox`:

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents LostFocus="function(s, e) {
        if (s.GetText() == '')
        {
            s.SetIsValid(false);
            s.errorText = 'Please enter First Name.';
        }
    }"></ClientSideEvents>
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip">
    </ValidationSettings>
</dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

But the `errorText` displayed isn't what I have set inside the `LostFocus` event. Instead, the default `errorText` which is "*Invalid value*" is displayed in the tool tip.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to solve the problem:

```
        if (s.GetText() == '')
        {
            s.errorText = 'Please enter First Name.';
            s.SetIsValid(false);
        }
```

Modifying the value of `errorText` should come first before setting `IsValid` property of the `ASPxTextBox` to `false`.

(I want to laugh at my stupidness! OMG)

Thanks for those who helped. :)

Comment: I think this should for some of control's `clientsideevents`. Just before I thought of this, I was simulating client events other than `LostFocus`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this task, it is necessary to:

enable “required” validation (set the ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired property to “true”;

specify the “required” errorText (ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText);

force editor validation by setting the ValidationSettings.ValidateOnLeave property to “true”:

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents LostFocus="function(s, e) {
        s.Validate();
    }"></ClientSideEvents>
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" ValidateOnLeave="true">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="true" ErrorText="Please enter First Name." />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get this one, but I also need some custom validations, not just making the field required. Does this means that I can not solve the problem I stated above? Thanks :)